chrono-node month parsing issue
0
I've encountered a problem in which I am looking for a good solution.
I uses chrono-node for understanding which date the user is referring to , But chrono doesn't follows a strict rule in parsing month only sentences
ISSUE: The current month is July 2024
here only January month is considered as January 2025(next year) and all other months as this year(2024) months
The thing is if chrono consider months Before Current Month (as it is already finished) as next year months, it should be applicable for all months before current month, but here that is not followed
Is there any alternative methods or npms for this
const chrono = require('chrono-node');

function testMonthParsing() {
    const months = [
        'january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june',
        'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'
    ];

    months.forEach(month => {
        let date = chrono.parseDate(month);
        console.log(`${month}: ${date}`);
    });
}
testMonthParsing();

// january: Wed Jan  2025
// february: Thu Feb  2024
// march: Fri Mar  2024
// april: Mon Apr  2024
// may: Wed May  2024
// june: Sat Jun  2024
// july: Mon Jul  2024
// august: Thu Aug  2024
// september: Sun Sep  2024
// october: Tue Oct  2024
// november: Fri Nov  2024
// december: Sun Dec  2024 

